# How to notify another user like Facebook bell icon using livewire?

Tags: notifications, laravel-livewire

I have this method on `\Livewire\LeadManager.php`:

```
public function compartilharLead($brokerId, $leadId)
{
    $lead = Lead::find($leadId);
    if ($lead) {
        $lead->user_id = $brokerId;
        $lead->class = 'border-warning';
        $lead->save();

        User::find($brokerId)->notify(new LeadRecebido($lead));
        $this->emit('LeadCompartilhado');
        $this->emit('hideModal');
        $this->mount();
    } else {
        $this->emit('exibirToastErro', 'ERRO', 'Lead não encontrado!');
    }
}
```

This is working fine for my user, but nothing happens on another browser window with another user logged in.
Two browser windows open, on normal navigation and one private navigation, me and another user logged in.
When I do share a lead to me, it works fine, the bell icon shows up a new message just like on Facebook, but when I share to the other user, nothing happens unless I do reload the page.

Let's see some more code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class Notifications extends Component
{
    public $novosLeads;
    protected $listeners = ['LeadCompartilhado' => 'atualizaLeads'];


public function mount()
{
    $this->pegaLeads();
}

public function atualizaLeads()
{
    $this->pegaLeads();
    $this->render();
}

public function pegaLeads()
{
    $this->novosLeads = Auth::user()->unreadNotifications;
}

public function marcarComoLido($leadId)
{
    $lead = Auth::user()->notifications()->where('id', $leadId)->first();
    if ($lead) {
        $lead->markAsRead();
        $this->pegaLeads(); // Atualizar a lista após marcar como lido
    }
}

public function render()
{
    return view('livewire.notifications');
}
}
```

Must I use some kind of push service? Can't do this only with Livewire?

Comment: You'd need either [a push service of some kind](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/broadcasting), or `wire:poll` on the notification icon or one of its parents to periodically refresh it. The former will be much easier on your server with lots of users; the latter will be much simpler to implement.

Answer (score 0):

This awesome tutorial saved my life. Thanks dear @ceejayoz

[Reproduzir tudo
Laravel-Livewire Chat-Message app (Realtime) from scratch](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLvHNtXLkQ-zHYvs1k0ohWlGRwckSXfTA-)